# UART on Windows 10 IoT Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: c#, uart, windows-10-iot-core

I am trying to run the Windows 10 IoT Serial sample on the Pi2 found at https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/samples/SerialSample.htm - however, when I run the sample, I get a certain ID on the connected devices box, which is a Resource Hub Proxy Device ("ACPI\MSFT8000\1") - does anyone know why this would be and why I wouldn't be getting the device ID of the device that I've connected over UART.

Cheers,

Raymond

Answer (score -1):

I have successfully used the RPI2 UART with code based upon the serial example. Actually I was using it to access the USB-Serial port and the extra serial option appeared when I used a later build of the OS. My test was simple: I jumpered pins 8 and 10 and just sent data and it was instantly received. Make sure you have a recent build ( a few prior to 10856 (its coming soon) ) and the latest version of the IOT-Core Serial sample.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.